# Adding leading zeros to result from substring in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a substring which pulls the data I need but I need to add a leading zero to the front of the result. I've searched and found several samples of pulling data with leading zeros but none using a substring. I can add the zero to the end of the result but do not know how to add it to the front. The substring I am using is shown below.
"substring((substring(convert(char(6),Convert(int,a.nor_ppd_hrs_no*100) + 100000),3,4) +    space(16)),1,16) as 'ApprovedHrs',"
This produces a result like this 7500 and I need it to look like this 07500.

Thanks

Comment: Is `012` a valid result, or must it be `00012`?

Comment: Do you want these numbers to be left aligned (with a column width of 16 chars) ?

Comment: If the two digits in the table are 72 we need the result to be 07200. The original code adds the two zeros at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the resulting string to be 5 characters length,

```
 stuff(substring((substring(convert(char(6),Convert(int,a.nor_ppd_hrs_no*100) + 100000),3,4) + space(16)),1,16), 1, 0, replicate('0', 5 - len(substring((substring(convert(char(6),Convert(int,a.nor_ppd_hrs_no*100) + 100000),3,4) + space(16)),1,16)))) as 'ApprovedHrs
```

Comment: This provided the leading zero but for some reason the 5 character column grew to 256 characters. Any ideas?

Comment: which possibly means, your substring is returning strings that are more than 5 characters in length. Can you check the max length of your substring results?

Comment: Pulling just the raw data for that column the characters are 1 or 2 characters in length nothing longer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the STR() function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) to convert a number to a fixed-length, right-justified string.  By default, it pads with spaces, so replace `' '` with `'0'` to get a zero-padded output.

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(a.nor_ppd_hrs_no*100,5),' ','0') FROM MyTable
```